# C++ - Undefined Reference to function with multiple files

Tags: c++, reference, undefined, header-files

So, right now, I can run my code from the `sumtwonums.cpp` file but i get a lot of errors when i try to run it from the main. Ive been grinding this code out for a very long time and i can't quite seem to get it. (I'm a beginner at c++ so i know my code could be greatly improved).
Anyways, here is the error im getting when i try to run it from sum.

```
In function 'main':
16 C:\Users\jozef\Desktop\SYDE 2017\SYDE 121 LABS\Lab702\sum.cpp    undefined reference to `input(SumTwoNums&)
17 C:\Users\jozef\Desktop\SYDE 2017\SYDE 121 LABS\Lab702\sum.cpp    undefined reference to `input(SumTwoNums&)
18 C:\Users\jozef\Desktop\SYDE 2017\SYDE 121 LABS\Lab702\sum.cpp    undefined reference to `print(SumTwoNums&)'
19 C:\Users\jozef\Desktop\SYDE 2017\SYDE 121 LABS\Lab702\sum.cpp    undefined reference to `print(SumTwoNums&)'
20 C:\Users\jozef\Desktop\SYDE 2017\SYDE 121 LABS\Lab702\sum.cpp    undefined reference to `sum(SumTwoNums&, SumTwoNums&, int*)'
21  C:\Users\jozef\Desktop\SYDE 2017\SYDE 121 LABS\Lab702\sum.cpp   undefined reference to `print(int*)'
```

`sumtwonums.cpp` shown as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef SUMTWONUMS_H
#define SUMTWONUMS_H

const int LENGTH = 20;

struct SumTwoNums{
    public:
        int array[LENGTH];
        char c_array[LENGTH];
};
void input(SumTwoNums &s);
void sum(SumTwoNums &s1, SumTwoNums &s2, int s[]);
void print (SumTwoNums &s);
void print (int a[]);
#endif 

#include "sumtwonums.h"

using namespace std;


void sum(SumTwoNums &s1, SumTwoNums &s2, int s[]){
    for (int i = LENGTH-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if (s1.array[i] + s2.array[i] + s [i] > 9 && i != LENGTH-1){
            s [i] += (s1.array[i] + s2.array[i] - 10);
            s [i-1] += 1;
        }else if (s1.array[i] + s2.array[i] + s [i]<= 9 && i != LENGTH-1){
            s [i] += s1.array[i] + s2.array[i];
        }else if (i == LENGTH-1 && s1.array[i] + s2.array[i] + s [i]> 9 ){
            s[i] += s1.array[i] + s2.array[i];
            s[i-1] += 1;
        }else if (i == LENGTH-1 && s1.array[i] + s2.array[i] + s [i] <= 9 ){
            s[i] += s1.array[i] + s2.array[i];
        }else if (i == LENGTH-1 && s1.array[i] + s2.array[i] + s [i] > 9){///////
            s [i] += (s1.array[i] + s2.array[i]);                         ////Check To see if overflow
            cout << "There is an overflow" << endl;                       ///////
        }
    }
}
void input(SumTwoNums &s){
    int dig = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
        s.array[i] = 0;
    }
    cout << "Please enter a number:\n";
char next;
int x = LENGTH-1;
cin.get(next);
while (next != '\n' && next != 'E' && x >= 0){  
    dig++;   
    s.c_array[x] = next;
    cin.get(next);
    x--;
}
for (int i = 1; i <= LENGTH; i++){
    if (dig != 0) {
        s.array[LENGTH - dig] = s.c_array[LENGTH - i] - '0';
        dig--;
        }
    }   
}

void print (SumTwoNums &s){
    int count = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i <  LENGTH ; i++){
        if (s.array[i] != 0 || ( s.array[i - 1] != 0 && s.array[i] == 0 && s.array[i + 1] != 0)){
                cout << s.array[i];
            if (count%3==0 && count != 0 && i != LENGTH-1){
                cout << ",";
            }
        }
        count++;
}
cout << endl;
}
void print (int a[]){
    int count = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i <  LENGTH ; i++){
        if (a[i] != 0 || ( a[i - 1] != 0 && a[i] == 0 && a[i + 1] != 0)){
                cout << a[i];
            if (count%3==0 && count != 0 && i != LENGTH-1){
                cout << ",";
            }
        }
        count++;
}
cout << endl;
}
```

`sum.cpp` shown as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sumtwonums.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    SumTwoNums num1;
    SumTwoNums num2;
    int total [LENGTH];
    int rtotal [LENGTH];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
        total[i] = 0;
        rtotal[i] = 0;
    }

    input(num1);
    input(num2);
    print(num1);
    print(num2);
    sum (num1,num2,total);
    print(total);

    return 0;
}
```

I know this question has been asked before, but i couldn't find an answer that i understand properly. Thank you.

Comment: How do you build your program? You do link with all object files, or use all source files when building?

Comment: What is the `sum.cpp` file?

Answer (score 0):

You should divide sumtwonums.cpp in to two files to make them work.

sumtwonums.h

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef SUMTWONUMS_H
#define SUMTWONUMS_H

const int LENGTH = 20;

struct SumTwoNums{
    public:
        int array[LENGTH];
        char c_array[LENGTH];
};
void input(SumTwoNums &s);
void sum(SumTwoNums &s1, SumTwoNums &s2, int s[]);
void print (SumTwoNums &s);
void print (int a[]);

#endif
```

sumtwonums.cpp

```
#include "sumtwonums.h"

using namespace std;


void sum(SumTwoNums &s1, SumTwoNums &s2, int s[]){
    for (int i = LENGTH-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if (s1.array[i] + s2.array[i] + s [i] > 9 && i != LENGTH-1){
            s [i] += (s1.array[i] + s2.array[i] - 10);
            s [i-1] += 1;
        }else if (s1.array[i] + s2.array[i] + s [i]<= 9 && i != LENGTH-1){
            s [i] += s1.array[i] + s2.array[i];
        }else if (i == LENGTH-1 && s1.array[i] + s2.array[i] + s [i]> 9 ){
            s[i] += s1.array[i] + s2.array[i];
            s[i-1] += 1;
        }else if (i == LENGTH-1 && s1.array[i] + s2.array[i] + s [i] <= 9 ){
            s[i] += s1.array[i] + s2.array[i];
        }else if (i == LENGTH-1 && s1.array[i] + s2.array[i] + s [i] > 9){///////
            s [i] += (s1.array[i] + s2.array[i]);                         ////Check To see if overflow
            cout << "There is an overflow" << endl;                       ///////
        }
    }
}
void input(SumTwoNums &s){
    int dig = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
        s.array[i] = 0;
    }
    cout << "Please enter a number:\n";
char next;
int x = LENGTH-1;
cin.get(next);
while (next != '\n' && next != 'E' && x >= 0){  
    dig++;   
    s.c_array[x] = next;
    cin.get(next);
    x--;
}
for (int i = 1; i <= LENGTH; i++){
    if (dig != 0) {
        s.array[LENGTH - dig] = s.c_array[LENGTH - i] - '0';
        dig--;
        }
    }   
}

void print (SumTwoNums &s){
    int count = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i <  LENGTH ; i++){
        if (s.array[i] != 0 || ( s.array[i - 1] != 0 && s.array[i] == 0 && s.array[i + 1] != 0)){
                cout << s.array[i];
            if (count%3==0 && count != 0 && i != LENGTH-1){
                cout << ",";
            }
        }
        count++;
}
cout << endl;
}
void print (int a[]){
    int count = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i <  LENGTH ; i++){
        if (a[i] != 0 || ( a[i - 1] != 0 && a[i] == 0 && a[i + 1] != 0)){
                cout << a[i];
            if (count%3==0 && count != 0 && i != LENGTH-1){
                cout << ",";
            }
        }
        count++;
}
cout << endl;
}
```